# write directory permissions in Jupyter

Tags: python, ubuntu, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I'm trying to import the mnist database using pytorch in Jupyter:

```
train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
  torchvision.datasets.MNIST('/files/', train=True, download=True,
                             transform=torchvision.transforms.Compose([
                               torchvision.transforms.ToTensor(),
                               torchvision.transforms.Normalize(
                                 (0.1307,), (0.3081,))
                             ])),
  batch_size=batch_size_train, shuffle=True)
```

However I don't know how, or where to grant permissions to Jupyter so it can do so and thus I get

**PermissionError**

```
/miniconda3/envs/PytorchEnv/lib/python3.6/os.py in makedirs(name, mode, exist_ok)
    218             return
    219     try:
--> 220         mkdir(name, mode)
    221     except OSError:
    222         # Cannot rely on checking for EEXIST, since the operating system

PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/files'
```

I'm using Ubuntu.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, I think your path is `./files/`, rather than `/files/`. The path `/files/` is an absolute path.

If you really want to use `/files/`, you can start jupyter by the command to get root permission:

```
jupyter notebook --allow-root
```